# Is "except" the correct word in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Several Punnett squares illustrating these interactions are noted on
>   the next page. Note that females are likely to be color blind 33
>   percent of the time while males are likely to be color blind 50
>   percent of the time in these interactions. This is also illustrated on
>   the following page.
>
> **All possible sex-linked trait crosses *except* color blindness**
>   (The list of test crosses ONLY FOR color blindness follows.)
>   1. ...
>   2. ...
>   3. ...
>   4. ...

In the book, there is only one chart. Although the title of this single chart says there are all crosses EXCEPT those for color blindness, there are actually crosses ONLY FOR color blindness.
The word except means not including, but, besides. Doesn't it mean then that all possible sex-linked trait crosses are included other than test crosses for color blindness? Is it just a mistake in the book or some other meaning of the word in the context?

Comment: Elena, would you please quote the complete sentence in the beginning?

"All possible sex-linked trait crosses except color blindness"

Comment: @Sina, actually it is a complete title before the list of test crosses, but I can include a few previous sentences as well

Comment: You could also say **other than** or **excluding** or **except for**. Or you could put the color-blindness table first and then put "**Other** sex-linked trait crosses" as the label for the second table.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo wait; so you mean it is a mistake there? (I'm not sure if I wrote the citation in the right way; in the book, there is only one chart. Although the title of this single chart says there are all crosses EXCEPT those for color blindness, there are actually crosses ONLY FOR color blindness.)

Comment: Ah, I thought "The list of test crosses ONLY FOR color blindness follows" meant follows *below*, that is, *after* the list of crosses that excluded color blindness.  **except color blindness** means "not including color blindness".

Comment: 'crosses' meaning what in this context?

Comment: @SeanHoulihane, they are Punnett squares which is a term in biology that means a male and female individuals are dating and we make crosses of their genetic material to predict what genetic material their offspring would possibly have. In this context, we make crosses for a trait of color blindness (for example, color blind male + color blind female = ?; not color blind male + a female who is a carrier for color blindness = ?) to see the possibility in every case that an offspring would have/not have/be a carrier for color blindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any interpretation of the bold sentence matching the context in this you have quoted it.

'all possible' implies that this is a table which either applies to everything XX+XY->XX/XY which has a different expression to colour blindness, or it's tabulating the traits which are not similar to colour blindness.

'except' does mean that the table is not about colour blindness, and it is about other things.

This means that either you are wrong about your interpretation of what the table shows, or the text is wrong. You can confirm by cross checking against other texts.